# Geometric realization commutes with infinite products of Kan Complexes up to weak homotopy equivalence

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Geometric realization of simplicial sets doesn't commute with infinite products in general, even up to weak homotopy equivalence. However, it does when we restrict to Kan complexes. This is not hard to show. Is there a good reference for this fact?

Comment: When I say it's not hard to show, I should add that there are many ways of thinking about this fact. Some make it more blindingly obvious than others. Part of the problem is that in much of the literature, one would see this as obvious because geometric realization, when correctly formulated, induces an equivalence of homotopy categories, and so would not even bother to state the above fact explicitly. It's tricky to find a reference which doesn't have access to this or similar ways of thinking, but still has reason to need this fact at all.

Comment: How about "On the algebraic K-theory of infinite product categories" by Gunnar Carlsson? Unfortunately I can't access the paper right now, but I think the result is proved there.

Comment: @GregoryArone Thanks, I've gotten a copy and will take a look. He mentions in the introduction that he will at some point in the paper observe that homotopy groups commute with products of Kan complexes, which leads to the low-tech proof I had in mind, but I still need to look closer to see if he states this fact. Just wanted to thank you before I forget!